# How can I get Safari to open in desktop instead of its own space?

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

When I open Safari, it opens in its own application desktop, instead of in one of Lion's desktops. The problem this creates is that I have to keep on changing back and forth to the desktop which TextMate uses.

How can I get Safari to open in a "normal" desktop.

Comment: I followed the directions given in the answer, but Safari opens in its own desktop instead of opening in any of the numbered desktops. I check my Safari preferences to see if there is anything about opening in its own desktop but could not find anything. In short, the answer given did not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are having problems with the [full-screen](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/full-screen.html) feature which was introduced in lion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and illustrations.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help!